# ScrollView is not working properly with showing/hiding keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

Step 1: I have a textfield which is embedded in a scrollview, when I start editing the textfield, keyboard appears and I am changing scrollview insets accordingly.

Step 2: while keyboard is active I presented a viewcontroller, and came back.

step 3: Now if I start editing textfield again, the scrollview is stuck and not moving up as it was earlier.

Comment: Explain with coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add observers with two selectors `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillShow` to the `NotificationCenter.default` you can try this

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    super.keyboardWillShow(notification)

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        scrollView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardSize.height
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    super.keyboardWillHide(notification)

    scrollView.contentInset.bottom = 0
}
```